# RxJava - very long delay

Tags: java, rx-java, system.reactive

I need to use delay operator of RxJava. Can anyone explain how it works? Does the thread sleep during delay? How exact the delay is? I need to emit item almost after 1 day (24 hours delay) in worst case.

Comment: Wow, I don't think RxJava is the correct tool for this.

Comment: RxJava uses the standard Java `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` class for its delay operations thus the accuracy is dependent on the JDK and platform you are running on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're not here to do your work for you. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to write a good, answerable question. You need to show what you have done so far to solve your problem by posting your code.

Comment: There are several possible solutions to this problem. You may use a cron-job library or you could use RxJava for this task. I would say it depends on your logic. With a RxJava approach you would need to block main-thread from exiting. But it would be easy to test, if the job fires every 24h hours. You would use a TestScheduler for this.

Comment: grammatical corrections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the delay operator we delay the creation of the pipeline from lazy to eager.
But once start emitting the delay operator does not affect the items emitted

```
@Test
public void delayCreation() {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Subscription subscription = Observable.just("hello reactive world")
            .delay(200, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
            .subscribe(n -> System.out.println("time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)));
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription).awaitTerminalEvent(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

You can see more examples of delay here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/utils/ObservableDelay.java